# Create Table: Keep one row/value for each category type (DAX)

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax

In `DAX` or `Power BI`, does anyone by any chance know how to create a new table based on, for instance, the maximum value of each category in a table? Hereunder is a simplified table of the columns I have, and further down what I want to obtain.

```
Categories = \[a, a, b, b, c, c\]

Values = \[1, 7, 8, 1, 9, 1\]

New_Categories = \[a, b, c\]

New_Values = \[7, 8, 9\]
```

`CALCULATE(MAX(Table[Value]), ALLEXCEPT(Table, Table[Category]))` gave me the maximum value for each category, nonetheless, I don't know how to use it to filter out only those rows into a new table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`SUMMARIZE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/summarize-function-dax) to summarize a table. Then, optionally, use [`SELECTCOLUMNS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/selectcolumns-function-dax) if you want to rename the columns.

See below example.

```
My New Table = 
  SELECTCOLUMNS(
    SUMMARIZE(
      'Table',
      'Table'[Categories],
      "Values", MAX('Table'[Values]),
      "Values 2", MAX('Table'[Values 2])
    ),
    "New_Categories", [Categories],
    "New_Values", [Values],
    "New_Values 2", [Values 2]
  )
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Fair point. Point taken, thank you.

Comment: Thank you very much, however, this leads me to the next problem - How do I keep a third column? 
 
 Categories = [a, a, b, b, c, c]
 
 Values = [1, 7, 8, 1, 9, 1]
 
 Values 2 = [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
 
 New_Categories = [a, b, c]
 
 New_Values = [7, 8, 9]
 
New_Values 2 = [4, 4, 4]

Comment: See above updated answer, provided links to these two functions as well. Please mark answer as Accepted for the benefit of all.